# MYSQL Stored Procedure only updates on record

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

MYSQL Stored Procedure only updates one record when it should update all the ids in the *WHERE id IN* clause. When I run the SELECT and UPDATE outside of the stored procedure it works fine. Any suggestions?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_ids(IN source int(10),IN target int(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE idList varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL;
    SET idList = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') FROM myTable ii WHERE ii.generic_id = source);
    UPDATE myTable i SET i.generic_id = target WHERE i.id IN (idList);

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then I call it by -->

```
CALL update_generic_ids(63, 1258);
```

Update : 1 row effected.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you looked in the table to see how many rows were actually affected? This might just be your query tool's way of saying "1 procedure executed ok"

Comment: Did you check the content of `idList`? Could be that you only get one result, or maybe as Caius said, 1 procedure executed

Comment: Ps, I'm not certain that the way you're running your separate test and your procedure logic amount to the same thing. It's one thing to run a select that returns a string full of comma delimited IDs, copy it, paste it into a. Update query in your query tool and run the update, but you can't put a string full of IDs into a variable and then pass the single variable into an in list- the db won't look at it as a list of id numbers. It will look at it as a single string full of numerals and commas. If you don't have a row with an Id that is literally '1,2,3,4' then the query won't work!

Comment: E.g. Tell us if you don't understand the difference between these two queries: `UPDATE a SET b = c WHERE d IN ('1,2,3,4')` versus `UPDATE a SET b = c WHERE d IN (1,2,3,4)`

Answer (score 0):

once try below chunk of code, hope it will solve your problems!
If any question reach me!

`DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE update_ids(IN source int(10),IN target int(10))
BEGIN
    DECLARE idList varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL;
    --SET idList = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(id SEPARATOR ', ') FROM myTable ii WHERE ii.generic_id = source);
    UPDATE myTable i SET i.generic_id = target WHERE i.id IN (
        SELECT  id FROM myTable ii WHERE ii.generic_id = source
    );`

END$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: You can clean up the code and ditch the idlist stuff too, if you like

Comment: Thanks, Caius! appreciate your comment, but it's a small piece of code, and purpose will be solved the problem. anyway, thanks  :)

Comment: Yeah, I always felt that people with the knowledge had a responsibility to teach it well to others, but if you think it's fine to fix up someone's broken program by leaving in X lines of useless code above after you copy one of those lines down to the end of the program then who am I to dissuade you!? StackOverflow is supposed to be about generating good answers, not doing the minimum amount of effort so you can be the fastest gun in the west and grab that rep...

Comment: don't take it personally, If  1000 lines of code to make your life hell! better than write or solve problem within your codes!

Comment: I pray I never have to work on any code that you wrote :)

Comment: Let folk decide, I will pray I always meet more guys where I can fight with my knowledge, not with stupid writing skills.

Comment: @hackthisjay asked question and  I reply with same way, so it doesn't matter in which language you reply the although motive is solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as per my comments, I think is may be the answer..

There's a world of difference between these two queries:

```
UPDATE a SET b = c WHERE d IN ('1,2,3,4')

UPDATE a SET b = c WHERE d IN (1,2,3,4)
```

I'd recommend you amend your procedure so you're not storing your list of ids in a string variable. Actually you shouldn't need to store anything, just put the list generated by the select into the update:

```
    UPDATE myTable i SET i.generic_id = target 
    WHERE i.id IN 
       (SELECT id SEPARATOR FROM myTable ii WHERE ii.generic_id = source);
```